# Excel concat function

Tags: excel, vba

I need a little bit of help. I'm trying to create a macro.
It's for hotel vacancies.

Column `F2:F8` lists vacancy or occupied.
Column `A2:A8` lists the room numbers.

I'm trying to create a macro that will list the room numbers in a different cell, if their corresponding room is vacant. I'm truly grateful for all your help!

```
=concat((a2:a8)If(f2:f8,"vacant"))???
```

Comment: CONCAT is not a macro, It is a built in function available with Office 365 Excel.  Nor is it VBA

Answer (score 1):

use TEXTJOIN as it will allow the addition of a delimeter in an array form:

```
=TEXTJOIN(", ",TRUE,IF(F2:F8 = "vacant",A2:A8,""))
```

Being an array formula it needs to be confirmed with Ctrl-Shift-Enter instead of Enter when exiting edit mode.  If done correctly then Excel will put `{}` around the formula.

[image]